# Using WMI to uninstall programs

Tags: c#, wmi, uninstallation

I want to uninstall a program using WMI, but I get this error : "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))". Installing it worked without any problems, using the same ConnectionOptions. 
Is there any possibility that the Administrator user has rigths to install software, but not to uninstall? If so, how can I edit them?

```
Main()
{
        ConnectionOptions oConn = new ConnectionOptions();
        oConn.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        oConn.EnablePrivileges = true;
        oConn.Username = "Administrator";
        oConn.Password = "password";

        System.Management.ManagementScope oMs = 
            new System.Management.ManagementScope("\\\\192.168.14.128\\root\\cimv2", oConn);

        Uninstall(oMs, "\\\\192.168.14.128\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Product.IdentifyingNumber=    \"{926C96FB-9D0A-4504-8000-C6D3A4A3118E}\",Name=\"Java DB 10.4.2.1\",Version=\"10.4.2.1\"");

}

    static void Uninstall(ManagementScope oMs, string path)
    {
        if (!oMs.IsConnected) oMs.Connect();
        ManagementObject product = new ManagementObject(path);

        if ((product != null) && (product.Path.ClassName ==
        "Win32_Product"))
        {
            object result = product.InvokeMethod("Uninstall", null); //here is where I get the error
            Console.WriteLine("The Uninstall method result is {0}",
            result.ToString());
        }
   }
```

Thank You!

Comment: Is the application in use or is a file locked at the time you try to uninstall?

Comment: No. uninstalling manually (from add remove programs) works without any problems

Comment: any solutions with sample code ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this on an XP machine? I just Google-d your error number and got a couple links to this: http://www.0x80070005.net/. There's a lot of information about the problem, and here's a copy and paste:

> The error 0x80070005 often occurs when
>   a scheduled task in Task Scheduler in
>   Windows becomes corrupt, you need to
>   install a security update which will
>   receive an error message. The error
>   message usually shows “Access denied”.
>   Here it needs a vulnerability task
>   scheduler which will allow code
>   execution. These are security updates
>   which were issued in the earlier
>   bulletin. This needs a Microsoft
>   knowledge base. So it is clear that
>   this error is about the security issue
>   and it finds error in the access.

Also, we're using [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) for our installer solution. Not sure if it' something you can use, but I figured I would just throw it out there.

Comment: This problem occured on XP, yes. 
I am not trying to build a kit for my software and install it. I want to install/uninstall a software remotely, using WMI. 
I get this problem when trying to uninstalling remotely, not when installing. so this probably is not a Windows XP problem.